# How do i install xf86-input-synaptics-1.5.99.901-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz in ubuntu 11?

Tags: installation, driver, ubuntu-11.10

How do I install  `xf86-input-synaptics-1.5.99.901-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` in **ubuntu 11**?

I have found the file and downloaded the file from windows.

I don't have any idea of how to install the driver in ubuntu.

when searched how to install, I got the following

1. Enable the extra repository on `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

2. Install `xf86-input-synaptics` xz package:

```
pacman -Sy xf86-input-synaptics
```

i searched for the file in the folder but there is no such file existing?

please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable

```
[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

on

```
/etc/pacman.conf
```

Install xf86-input-synaptics xz package:

```
# pacman -Sy xf86-input-synaptics
```

Please take a look on http://pkgs.org/archlinux/archlinux-extra-i686/xf86-input-synaptics-1.5.99.901-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz.html

Please refer google for get better https://www.google.com/search?q=install+package+in+ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: actually there is a problem... there isn't any pacman.conf file in my /etc/ folder how do I find the file? any links available for those files

Comment: Are you sure it is not somewhere? Try in shell to run `updatedb; locate pacman.conf;` if nothing show up...

Comment: @ashishkawade Do you have check in etc folder.if you have some problem you need to try stackoverflow person's method